# How to authenticate user base on JWT API - Laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jwt

I'm using PHP 7.2 on Laravel 5.8.

I current use Auth provider that came with Laravel to log my users in.

It currently check if the email, and password match in the database configured.

I did this

```
$dbAuth = Auth::attempt(array(
    'email' => $email,
    'password' => $password
));

if ($dbAuth) {

    return Redirect::to('/dashboard')->with('success', 'You have been successfully logged in.');

} else {
    return Redirect::to('/')->with('error', 'Username/Password Wrong')->with('email', $email)->withErrors($validator);
}
```

I can't do that anymore, I have to talk to call an API that return a token.

---

Just to clarify :

My main goal is to call JWT API, and logged my user in if I got the 200 response.

How do log my users in now?

Comment: You should consult https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport.

Comment: [this tutorial](https://medium.com/techcompose/create-rest-api-in-laravel-with-authentication-using-passport-133a1678a876) is pretty decent if you just want a simple token-based API without having to learn anything about oauth2.

Comment: Tutorial requests are off-topic here. From the official close reasons: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use this package for JWT auth, it has a good documentation as well.

https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth